# Finger.IsExtended Leap Motion C#

Tags: c#, leap-motion

I want to detect the finger bending using a windows forms application in c#.

I have difficulty to add (I read it from [this](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/api/Leap.Finger.html#csharpclass_leap_1_1_pointable_1aa5f9c23366996e146de0128391996bdc)):

```
HandList hands = frame.Hands;
FingerList fingers = hands.Fingers;

int extendedFingers = 0;
for (int f = 0; f < hands.Fingers.Count; f++)
{
    Finger digit = hands.Fingers[f];
    if(fingers.IsExtended) extendedFingers++;
    label1.Text = f.ToString();
}
```

because error appear one of them in second line of the program, and it said that

> "Leap.Handlist does not contain definition of a "Fingers""

Have I missed something?

And where do I have to add those program, if I try from [this one](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/devguide/Project_Setup.html)?

is in the `void newFrameHandler(Frame frame)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Leap.Handlist does not contain definition of a "Fingers""

Presumably a Handlist is similar to an array.  I would expect a single `Hand` to define `Fingers`, not an array of `Hands`.

You need a

## HAND

not

#### HAND_S_

Comment: thank you, you mean I have to change HandList hand = frame.Hands; ? I have changed it but still the error occurs

Comment: No.  I mean `Hands` is plural (many).  Each `Hand` (singular, one) will define fingers.

Comment: oh thank you, I have change to Hand hand = frame.Hand(0); FingerList fingers = hand.Fingers; and no error occurs. but for the second question I still can not get the label1 get the input

Comment: I don't know.  Try using the debugger in Visual Studio.

Comment: frame.Hand(0) does not give you what you think -- it looks for a hand with ID=0. What you want is frame.Hands[0], which is the first element in the hands array.